# Unable to parse json string in aws cli to add notification configuration to s3 bucket

Tags: json, aws-cli

I am trying to add SNS topic to a s3 bucket and I am using the  aws cli command to apply a notification configuration to s3bucket called 'test'

I am passing the SNS topic configuration as a json string and when I try to print the json string its printing the json value correctly but somehow aws cli add commas to the json string.

inputevent.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
bucketName=test
jsonInput=file:///Users/ish/GitLabProject/validator-cf/inputevent.json
QueueArn="arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:255353535355:SNSTopic"
template='{ "TopicConfigurations": { "Event": "s3:ObjectCreated:*", "Queue": "%s" } }'


TopicConfiguration=$(printf "$template" "$QueueArn")

echo "$TopicConfiguration"

aws s3api put-bucket-notification-configuration --bucket $bucketName --notification-configuration $TopicConfiguration
```

Error:

```
{ "TopicConfigurations": { "Event": "s3:ObjectCreated:*", "Queue": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:255353535355:SNSTopic" } }
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help

Unknown options: {, "Event":, "s3:ObjectCreated:*",, "Queue":, "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:255353535355:SNSTopic", }, }, "TopicConfigurations":
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `template` variable.

Based on the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-notification-configuration.html#options), the `TopicConfigurations` in the `--notification-configuration` should be an array (since you can have multiple notifications)

Try updating the `template` variable in your bash script to something like

```
template='{ "TopicConfigurations": [{ "Event": "s3:ObjectCreated:*", "Queue": "%s" }] }'
```

Can check the [examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-notification-configuration.html#examples) to get a better idea